# Two UI-definitions for one dialgue?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have an Qt-application where dialogues make use of standard XML UI-files which are compiled into the code. They have a standard structure where a class name is defined for this UI file and afterwards I can access the members (=GUI elements) via an object which is an instance of this UI-class (code snippets out of .ui file, ui_*.h file and dialogue implementation):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <ui version="4.0">
  <class>DlgClass</class>
  ...

namespace Ui {
   class DlgClass : public Ui_DlgClass {};
} // namespace Ui

Ui::DlgClass ui;

ui.heightCaption->setMinValueTextColor(Qt::black);
```

Now my problem: For some dialogues I want to have two or more layouts where the design is different but which contain exactly the same GUI elements (but at an different position). Next I need to access these elements in exactly the same way like before, means by pointer access to an object which is of a type defined by the UI file.

My problem: when I create two UI files which then are compiled, they have different class names I can't map onto each other easily. So: how can this be solved? Is it possible to define a common base class for usage with two different UI files? Or what else could be done here? Loading and interpreting an UI file during runtime is not a solution, this is way too slow.

Thanks!

Comment: How would you choose which layout to setup in the Dialog? is that based on some argument that is passed to the dialog constructor for example?

Comment: @Mike: yes, this is correct, the application gets this information on start-up, no on-the-fly changing of the layout is planned